# Using overridePendingTransition() to animate the first Activity

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm trying to use `overridePendingTransition()` to animate the very first Activity - the one that gets created when the user launches the app. Is this possible?

Where should I call  `overridePendingTransition()`?
Tried right after `super.onCreate()` and right after `super.onStart()` , but it didn't work.

I would prefer to manage this at runtime, rather than setting the @anim in a custom style. Couldn't find anything. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from experience all I will say is it will not **WORK** to make it *work*  you need to use a workaround, which is create a transparent launcher activity, carrying the app name and everything without a `View` (that is do not set content view) and make it transparent as I said with this code `this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));` and immediately call your "in real life splash screen or launcher activity", and put `this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.grow_from_middle,R.anim.shrink_to_middle);` in its `onresume()` (anywhere you prefer, I prefer this) and *voila* you have it..

Comment: what about performance? I feel like this could really show things down.

Comment: Let's say I "think" :) Anyway I was talking about launching times rather than system performance. Gonna try on some old device and let you know.